# How to pass a jwt token created on backend while authenticating with oauth2?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

So i have a custom frontend login Page in reactJS. As backend i am using springboot. In the backend i am using the oauth2client for the social login and on success authentication i am using an override of void onAuthenticationSuccess(). In this method i register the user in my DB, if not already present, and i create a custom jwt token. Now here Is the problem: how do i pass this jwt to the client ? I can do a redirect on My frontend and put the token as request param but It seems a Little bit concerning from a security point of view. I really have no idea of what Is the best solution in this scenario. Can you please suggest something

I tried the request param solution but i do not think It Is ok

Answer (score 1):

I suggest utilizing HTTP Headers for the following reasons:

- To ensure maximum security, it's advisable to incorporate the JWT token within the HTTP headers of your API responses.
- Once a user logs in successfully, your Spring Boot backend can generate the JWT token and embed it within the Authorization header of the response.
- On the ReactJS side, you can retrieve the token from the response headers and securely store it (e.g., in the browser's local storage or a cookie).
- For future requests to protected endpoints, the token should be
  included in the Authorization header of the request.

For example:

```
// Spring Boot (Java)
response.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwtToken);
// ReactJS (Axios)
axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
```